# AJAX call failing behind corporate firewall

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery, xmlhttprequest

I'm using jQuery's $.ajax() method to get about 26KB of JSONP data.

The data is returned perfectly in FF, Chrome, IE, and Safari from every location I've tested it (work, home, mobile phone, etc.).

The only exception is one of my clients who attempted to access the site from behind his company's firewall. Unfortunately, I was unable to get him to provide me with the response, but I know my success function is executing - so it seems that the response is being corrupted somehow, since anything that references the returned JSON is coming up undefined.

My question is this: is it possible that a firewall would place restrictions on the length of XHR responses? Is there some other obvious explanation that maybe I'm missing?

Many thanks.

**UPDATE:**

For anyone who happens to stumble upon this post... I had completely forgotten that the AJAX call was to one of my development servers using non-standard ports. Pretty sure that's why his firewall didn't like it.

Thanks to all who commented.

Comment: Are you sure the client isn't using some horribly old browser?

Comment: Yeah. He tried with with FF 4 and Chrome 10.

Comment: If your client has FF4, maybe you could give him a quick crash course in FireBug's Console?  So that you know what the actual response is.

Comment: ... or ask him to share you a screen using TeamViewer

Answer (score 0):

I was going to suggest that apart from you messing up the urls, some firewalls have active filtering of requests, which might strip relevant java script calls from your requests (paranoid networks make for unique development environments).

Just a heads up to people that might be scratching their head in the future when their apps work here, there but not OVER there in a corporate setting.